# WPF set width of control by binding in centimeter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to set the width of my control by binding and in centimeters. (it's for the size of my printout so I find it easy to work with centimeters)

So I want to do something like this:

```
 <FlowDocument x:Name="flowdocument" PageWidth="{Binding Barcode.Width}" PageHeight="{Binding BarcodeSjabloon.Height}">
```

but I want to set it in centimeters like this:

```
 <FlowDocument x:Name="flowdocument" PageWidth="20cm" PageHeight="30cm">
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a converter that understands your syntax and uses the [current DPI setting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/03/07/getting-system-dpi-in-wpf-app.aspx) to convert to an appropriate number of pixels.